# Nothing is displayed when I run this JavaScript code to print an array.What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I just started learning JavaScript.

I'm trying to display a one-dimensional array of numbers from 0 to 9 using JavaScript.

Output : 
nothing is displayed on the screen.

Can you let me know where I went wrong.Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
  <body>
  <script>

   var num = new array();

   for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
   num[i]=i;

   for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
   document.write(num[i]+"<br>");
  </script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive (it's Array not array). At least chrome and firefióx have a javascript console that displays this kind of error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistake is 1st line of the script.
`array` should be `Array`

Answer (score 0):

change line

```
var num = new array()
```

to

```
var num = new Array()
```

array needs an upper case A.

Answer (score 0):

Fix declaration to *var num = [];*

Debug your's code in Chrome console (F12)